# ERROR logstash.agent Failed to execute action

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

[logstash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFOcW.jpg)

`[ERROR] [logstash.agent ]Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java:: JavaLa :: IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (RuntimeError) \n\n\tyou might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case the is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with lock_jars` command\n\nno such file to`your text` load -- io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.93.Final/netty-transport-native-un
<-common-4.1.93. Final.jar (LoadError)", :backtrace=> ["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.(CompiledPipeline.java:120)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineE
:.initialize(AbstractPipelineExt.java:186)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipeline Ext$INVOKER$i$initialize.call(AbstractPipeline Ext$INVOKER$i$initialize.gen)", "org.jru
.internal.runtime.methods. JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:846)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper (IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1229)", "org.jruby
r.instructions. InstanceSuper Instr.interpret (InstanceSuper Instr.java:131)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter. Interpreter Engine.processCall (Interpreter Engine.java:361)", "org.jrub
ir.interpreter. Startup InterpreterEngine.interpret (Startup Interpreter Engine.java:72)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods. MixedModeIRMethod. INTERPRET_METHOD (MixedMode IRMe
hod.java:128)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods. MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:115)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall (CachingCa
Site.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance (RubyClass.java:911)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$I
VOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall (CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.cal
site.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions. CallBase.interpret (CallBase.java:549)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter. InterpreterEngine.process
11(Interpreter Engine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter. Startup Interpreter Engine. interpret (Startup Interpreter Engine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter. Interpreter Eng
e.interpret (Interpreter Engine.java:92)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods. MixedModeIRMethod. INTERPRET_METHOD (MixedModeIRMethod.java:238)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.